# How to set as a default value in a Symfony 2 form field the authentified username from the session of FOSUserBundle

Tags: forms, symfony, components

my builder is 
 private $username;

```
public function __construct(  $username = null) {
    $this->username = $username;
}

/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
            ->add('titre')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('contenu')
            ->add('categorie')
            ->add('site', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => array('ALM' => 'Aujourdhui le Maroc', 'LVE' => 'Lavieéco', 'FDM' => 'Femmes du Maroc', 'Nissaa' => 'Nissa min almaghrib'),
                'required' => false,
            ))
            ->add('Journaliste', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Journaliste',
                'data' => $this->username))
            ->add('Webmaster', 'entity', array('class' => 'Work\frontBundle\Entity\Utilisateurs', 'property' => 'id', 'multiple' => false))
            ->add('image')
            ->add('Valider')
            ->add('Envoyer', 'submit')
    ;
}
```

and the controller  $a = new Article();
        $username=$this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getUsername();
        $form = $this->createForm(new \Work\frontBundle\Form\ArticleType($username), $a);
        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {

```
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {




            $a->setsTitre($form['titre']->getData());
            $a->setDescription($form['description']->getData());
            $a->setContenu($form['contenu']->getData());
            $a->setCategorie($form['categorie']->getData());
            $a->setSite($form['site']->getData());
            $a->setImage($form['image']->getData());
            $a->setWebmaster($form['Webmaster']->getData());
            $a->setValider($form['Valider']->getData());
            $a->setJournaliste($form['Journaliste']->getData());
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $em->persist($a);
            $em->flush();
        }
    }
    return $this->render('WorkfrontBundle:Default:article.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

the setter 
and the setter

```
/**
 * Set journaliste
 *
 * @param \Work\frontBundle\Entity\Utilisateurs $journaliste
 * @return Article
 */
public function setJournaliste(\Work\frontBundle\Entity\Utilisateurs $journaliste = null)
{
    $this->journaliste = $journaliste;

    return $this;
}
```

but i got this probleme 
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Work\frontBundle\Entity\Article::setJournaliste() must be an instance of Work\frontBundle\Entity\Utilisateurs, string given, called in C:\wamp\www\stage\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor.php on line 442 and defined in C:\wamp\www\stage\src\Work\frontBundle\Entity\Article.php line 297

Comment: You expecting `Utilisateurs` entity in your `setJournaliste` but you pass only username not object. What is the `Utilisateurs` ? If it is user, then you must pass full user object, not username.

Comment: You have to change the value of $username to:

$username=$this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

Because you need to pass an entity, not the username, as malcolm said.

Comment: so how to do that please ?

Comment: it's dosent work with $username=$this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();